# When clicking "Reopen Closed Tab," Firefox does not reopen the most recent tab, but an older one - how do I fix this?

Tags: firefox, user-interface, tabbed-browsing

As stated in the title, within the past couple days, Firefox has started reopening an (apparently) random older closed tab when right clicking on a tab and selecting Reopen Closed Tab, even the most recent closed tab was *just* closed. I do not understand why this has started happening now, or how to make it stop happening. This does not happen only for closed tabs from a single site (neither in terms of the ones being "skipped" nor in terms of the older ones it opens instead). It is happening in a regular window, not a Private Browsing one. The Firefox Version is 102.12.0esr (64-bit), and I am using it on Debian Linux.

The only extensions I use are uBlock Origin and Privacy Badger, and have tested what happens if I disable these, close a tab, and then "Reopen Closed Tab," and it still reopens an ancient tab, not the one I just closed. Restarting the computer (and hence, the browser) did not work either. A little experimentation suggests that Reopen Closed Tab *is* (at least under some circumstances) working correctly in a Private Browsing window, while continuing to misbehave in a regular window that is open at the same time. (I will continue investigating.)

Can anyone explain how to fix this, or at least how to work around it?

Comment: Have you tried a new Firefox user profile?

Comment: @John Not yet. That's on my list of things to try, but since I have mutliple windows (each with numerous tabs) of work in progress, a "live" solution would obviously be a lot more convenient.

Comment: A live solution will be tough to get to though. Did you try disabling extensions? Did you try restarting the browser/system (could use some extension to save tabs if you're worried thr default feature for that is broken too).

Comment: @Destroy666 I tried disabling extensions; that did not help. I have not yet tried restarting the browser/system, although that, like a new user profile, is on my list of things to try.

Comment: Add any additional info to the question also please.